# Jquery Validation

Tags: jquery, плагин

как использовать JQuery  плагин для проверки списка формы

Comment: написано в документации

Comment: слишко общий вопрос. какой список? что в нём ты хочешь проверять ?  какие данные тебе подходят какие нет . в общем случае попробуй этот плагин https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Comment: из dropdownlist-тах проверить на валидацию только несколько документах